# <li>s misaligned inside <ul> with display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am a noob in `css`.I have two `<li>`s with `display:inline-block` inside a `ul` with different elements inside each of them.And they are misaligned.Below  given is the code that i have tried .

```
<div class="col-md-10 pa-zero ng-scope">
<ul style="border:1px solid blue">
    <li class="breadCrumb" style="font-size: 1.000em;margin-right:5px"> 
        <span class="pa-apply-font">Raw Materials : rm- </span>

    </li>
    <li class="breadCrumb" style="font-size: 1.000em; margin-right: 5px">
        <div>
            <button style="border: none; background-color: inherit;">Formulas (3)</button>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/n8pLb1v0/) is the Fiddle illustrating the problem.

I want them in the same line inside the `ul` wherein in the code that i have tried they are aligned in different lines inside the `ul`.Can you please help me resolve this.

Comment: edit your css code. there is  `vertical-align: middle;` in `.pa-apply-font{...}`. you remove and move to into `.breadCrumb`

Comment: Hei! Here is a fiddle. I added vertical-align: top; and line-height for li element. Looks good to me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline-block` elements have a default alignment of `baseline`.

Try using

```
vertical-align:top
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8pLb1v0/1/)

Comment: why is both `<li>`s  not taking the default alignment in this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DivyaMV Both the `li`s take the default baseline alignment. But the problem is, since both are of different heights, it gives this result. It is an expected result only.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this css. Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/dgxhs573/

```
.col-md-10 ul li {
  float: left;
}
.col-md-10 ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```